# execlp() in python

Tags: python

I was reading programming python 4th edition by Mark Luze, Oreilly, by teaching myself.
There's an example on how to fork a child process, which I do not quite understand:

```
os.execlp('python', 'python', 'child.py', #other args#)
```

In an interactive shell(like bash), I know I can type `python child.py #args#` to ask python interpreter to run child.py with args.
Why are there TWO 'python' in the execlp() function? If I put only one python in the function, I would get an error complainting cannot find file or directory, which is the 1st args of child.py

Comment: This originates in the `execlp` libc funciton, which you can get more info about using the command `man execlp`.

Comment: Here's the Open Group spec for the [exec family](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/exec.html) of POSIX functions. The general pattern of fork/exec in Unix hasn't changed much in 40 years.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first argument is the program to execute (found on the `PATH`). The rest are the `sys.argv` arguments to the program.

The *first* such argument is the program name used to invoke it, and the display value used in the OS process list. It is the value of `sys.argv[0]` in a python script.

Comment: Yeah. I got it. The 1st python is python file path, 2nd python is argv[0], and the rests are more args.

Comment: It's a pity this got downvoted, it looks as if [someone misunderstood this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174366/when-using-os-execlp-why-python-need-python-as-argv0/).

Comment: "The first argument is the program to execute" where "program" means the Python interpreter program in this case, not the user *.py Python program itself

Answer (score 5):

First of all, `execlp` is rarely used today. In most cases, you'd use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module, like this:

```
subprocess.call(['python', 'child.py'])
```

The first argument of [`execlp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp) is the file you want to execute.

The latter arguments form the argument array to that program ([`sys.argv`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv) in Python). The first argument is then the name the program got invoked with. For example, Python sets the name to `'-c'` if the program is being run with the `-c` option. Similarly, [grep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) behaves differently depending on the first argument, so that users can execute `rgrep` to imply `grep -r`.

Comment: I wouldn't assume that the latest edition is outdated -- it was published seven years after the `subprocess` module was included in the standard library.  It may be demonstrating how `fork()` and `exec()` work if you ever need to dig deeper.

Comment: subprocess.call does not replace the current process with the process it calls, which is an essential element of using execlp. subprocess.call is not a replacement for execlp.